# How come Noah has a different surname?

Tags: dark

Spoilers for season 3 of the German Netflix series 'DarK'

The real name of the character 'Noah' is revealed to be ['Hanno Tauber'](https://dark-netflix.fandom.com/wiki/Hanno_Tauber). However, in season 3, we get to learn that he is the son of

> Bartosz and Silja Tiedemann.

Then how come he has the surname 'Tauber' instead of

> 'Tiedemann'?

Comment: I suppose he used a false name to avoid questions.

Comment: Chances are it's just a name so as not to be Hanno Tiedamann in 1950's Winden while Egon and Doris are running around.  At the same time he is priest in 1950's Winden he is also Priest in 1986 Winden, but going by the name Noah.

I also find the name Tauber interesting, as spelt it means Deaf Man, and I kind of think it may refer to "hear no evil" as he was sort of plotting against Adam at this point.  Also just an interesting name for a priest, considering his "evil" nature on surface.

Comment: Doesn't really change much; but it's worth noting that Agnes doesn't take the name Tiedamann either.  Instead she seems to take the Neilson name; which is also strange. Though possibly explained by her relationship with the Unknown, and him taking the name from his mother.

Comment: https://dark.netflix.io/en/event-timeline/noah

Comment: Please note it's "Tiedemann" and "Nielsen".

Comment: @JMac also, Silja is the daughter of Egon Tiedemann and Hannah, who calls herself Katharina Nielsen after travelling back in time / is married to Ullrich Nielsen, so Silja would be have the surname Nielsen as well. Bartosz then takes his wife's name like his father did, making their daughter Agnes a Nielsen as well.

Comment: @SQB You raise a good point for the origin of the surname 'Nielsen'. However, there's no clear evidence to say that Bartosz took his wife's surname. Plus, the reason Aleksander took his wife's surname was to protect the story behind his stolen identity. Bartosz didn't have a problem like that.