# How come Agnes chose 'Nielsen' as her surname?

Tags: time-travel, dark

Spoilers for season 3 of the German Netflix series 'DarK'

In S03, Agnes' parents are revealed to be Bartosz and Silja. The most possible surname that Agnes could have gotten was *Tiedemann*, her father's surname.

Bartosz has the surname *Tiedemann* from his mother's side. While we are not really aware of what Silja's maiden name was, a theory(as mentioned in a [comment for this Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234407/how-come-noah-has-a-different-surname)) states that since Hannah Kahnwald was pretending to be Katharina Nielsen when she had an affair with Egon Tiedemann and eventually conceived Silja, she decided to give Silja the surname *Nielsen* instead of *Kahnwald* or *Tiedemann*, and then Bartosz adopted his wife's surname after the marriage (*Nielsen*).

However, the only exception of wife and children adopting husband's surname in DARK timeline was Aleksander Köhler adopting his wife Regina Tiedemann's surname. But that specific scenario can be explained via the fact that Aleksander Köhler was not his real name and he wanted to throw off any suspicions on his true identity in the future.

Meanwhile, Bartosz had no reason to adopt his wife's surname as he was far away from his original family. Plus, Silja is named as *Silja Tiedemann* in the [DARK Wikia](https://dark-netflix.fandom.com/wiki/Silja_Tiedemann) and [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5753856/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast).

What is the most plausible reason for Agnes to choose the surname *Nielsen*?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think Agnes’ maiden name is Agnes Tauber.  I think when Bartosz went into the past, he adopted a new name for himself, Bartosz Tauber.  Now I could be wrong about that; Noah could have changed his last name from Tiedemann to Tauber for whatever reason.  In that case Agnes’ maiden name would probably be Agnes Tiedemann.

But regardless, I think the reason her name changed to Agnes Nielsen is that she took the name of her ex-husband.  Who was her ex-husband?  It was The Unknown, the son of Jonas from Adam’s world and Martha from Eve’s world.  Now we never learn of a name for the Unknown, but I didn’t think it’s because he didn’t have one.  After all he lived a full life, he served as a priest, he got married, etc.

And I think that the last name he used as a priest, and perhaps all other stages of his life, was Nielsen.  This may have been due to his knowledge that Ulrich Nielsen was his paternal great-grandfather, or due to his knowledge that his descendants would bear the last name Nielsen, or maybe he just chose the name arbitrarily.  But regardless I think the name Nielsen passed from the Unknown to Agnes to Tronte and his descendants.

Comment: 1) Yes, in DarK wiki, Agnes is shown as 'Agnes Nielsen (born as Agnes Tauber)', so her maiden name is probably Tauber. 2) But, do we have any canon reference or any plausible explanation that why Bartosz changed his name to Tauber? He had no reason to change his original surname, as there were no Tiedemanns around in the 1890s. Plus, the wiki only lists him as 'Bartosz Tiedemann'. 3) Ulrich was not the paternal grandpa of The Unknown, I think you meant 'maternal'.

Comment: @Sandun Sorry I meant paternal great-grandfather.  In any case, I don’t know that there were no Tiedemann’s in the 1800’s (Claudia’s ancestors?), but regardless he may have just adopted a false name to hide his identity.